# Estimate_richness for all phyla in phyloseq

Tags: r, phyloseq

Is there an easy way to get ASV richness for each Phylum for each Station using the `estimate_richness` function in phyloseq? Or is there another simple way of extracting the abundance data for each taxonomic rank and calculating richness that way?

So far I have just been subsetting individual Phyla of interest using for example:

```
ps.Prymnesiophyceae <- subset_taxa(ps, Phylum == "Prymnesiophyceae")  
alpha_diversity<-estimate_richness(ps.Prymnesiophyceae,measure=c("Shannon","Observed"))  
H<-alpha_diversity$Shannon  
S1<-alpha_diversity$Observed  
S<-log(S1)  
evenness<-H/S
alpha<-cbind(Shannon=H,Richness=S1,Evenness=evenness,sample_data(Prymnesiophyceae))
```

But this is rather a pain when having to do it for e.g. the top 20 phyla.

EDIT:
suggestion by @GTM works well until last step. See comment + dput:

```
> dput(head(sample_names(ps.transect), n=2)) c("2-1-DCM_S21_L001_R1_001.fastq", "2-1-SA_S9_L001_R1_001.fastq" )
> dput(head(alpha, n=2)) structure(list(Observed = c(31, 25), Shannon = c(2.84184012598765, 
2.53358345702604), taxon = c("Prymnesiophyceae", "Prymnesiophyceae" ), sample_id = c("X2.1.DCM_S21_L001_R1_001.fastq", "X2.1.SA_S9_L001_R1_001.fastq" ), S = c(3.43398720448515,
3.2188758248682), evenness = c(0.827562817437384, 
0.787101955736294)), row.names = c("X2.1.DCM_S21_L001_R1_001.fastq",  "X2.1.SA_S9_L001_R1_001.fastq"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(smpl_data, n=1)) new("sample_data", .Data = list("001_DCM", 125L, structure(1L, .Label = "DCM", class = "factor"), structure(1L, .Label = "Transect", class = "factor"), structure(1L, .Label = "STZ", class = "factor"), 
    structure(1L, .Label = "STFW", class = "factor"), "Oligotrophic", 
    16L, -149.9978333, -29.997, 130.634, 17.1252, 35.4443, 1025.835008, 
    1.1968, 1e-12, 5.387, 2.8469, 52.26978546, 98.0505, 0, 0, 
    0.02, 0.9, 0, 0, 2069.47, 8.057, 377.3), names = c("Station_neat",  "Depth_our", "Depth_bin", "Loc", "Front", "Water", "Zone", "Bottle",  "Lon", "Lat", "pressure..db.", "Temperature", "Salinity", "Density_kgm.3",  "Fluorescence_ugL", "PAR", "BottleO2_mLL", "CTDO2._mLL", "OxygenSat_.",  "Beam_Transmission", "N_umolL", "NO3_umolL", "PO4_umolL", "SIL_umolL",  "NO2_umolL", "NH4_umolL", "DIC_uMkg", "pH", "pCO2_matm"), row.names = "2-1-DCM_S21_L001_R1_001.fastq", 
    .S3Class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could wrap you current code block in a for loop to go through each phylum and do the calculations. It might not be the most elegant, but it's a quick solution that uses the code you already have. You can obtain all unique phyla using `get_taxa_unique(physeq, taxonomic.rank='Phylum')`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @gmt! Would you be able to help me with the code for that? After a few years of using R, for loops are still a bit of a black box for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a for loop to do so. I've slightly modified your code to make it a bit more flexible, see below.

```r
require("phyloseq")
require("dplyr")

# Calculate alpha diversity measures for a specific taxon at a specified rank.
# You can pass any parameters that you normally pass to `estimate_richness`
estimate_diversity_for_taxon <- function(ps, taxon_name, tax_rank = "Phylum", ...){
  
  # Subset to taxon of interest
  tax_tbl <- as.data.frame(tax_table(ps))
  keep <- tax_tbl[,tax_rank] == taxon_name
  keep[is.na(keep)] <- FALSE
  ps_phylum <- prune_taxa(keep, ps)
  
  # Calculate alpha diversity and generate a table
  alpha_diversity <- estimate_richness(ps_phylum, ...)
  alpha_diversity$taxon <- taxon_name
  alpha_diversity$sample_id <- row.names(alpha_diversity)
  return(alpha_diversity)
}

# Load data
data(GlobalPatterns)
ps <- GlobalPatterns

# Estimate alpha diversity for each phylum
phyla <- get_taxa_unique(ps, 
                         taxonomic.rank = 'Phylum')
phyla <- phyla[!is.na(phyla)]
alpha <- data.frame()
for (phylum in phyla){
  a <- estimate_diversity_for_taxon(ps = ps, 
                                    taxon_name = phylum,
                                    measure = c("Shannon", "Observed"))
  alpha <- rbind(alpha, a)
}

# Calculate the additional alpha diversity measures
alpha$S <- log(alpha$Observed)
alpha$evenness <- alpha$Shannon/alpha$S

# Add sample data
smpl_data <- as.data.frame(sample_data(ps))
alpha <- left_join(alpha, 
                   smpl_data, 
                   by = c("sample_id" = "X.SampleID"))
```

This is a reproducible example with `GlobalPatterns`. Make sure to alter the code to match your data by replacing `X.SampleID` in the left join with the name of the column that contains the sample IDs in your `sample_data`. If there is no such column, you can create it from the row names:

```r
smpl_data <- as.data.frame(sample_data(ps))
smpl_data$sample_id < row.names(smpl_data)
alpha <- left_join(alpha, 
                   smpl_data, 
                   by = c("sample_id" = "sample_id"))
```

Comment: that works great thank you! The only issue I am having is that my sample_id in alpha gets screwed up in the process and I am not getting an X.sampleID row in smple_data as you did with global_patterns. Somehow my ps object seems a bit different but I can't work out where it's going wrong. I could correct this manually before merging of course but would still like to know the answer. I guess I can't put much code into this comment box so will dput into the original question

Comment: Glad it works. You need to adjust the code to match your data; `X.SampleID` is simply what sample IDs are called in `GlobalPatterns`. Replace`X.SampleID` with the name of the column in your `sample_data` that contains the sample IDs. If there is no column with sample IDs in your sample data, you can create one from the row names: `smpl_data$sample_id <- row.names(smpl_data)`.

Comment: I did that but if you check the dput rownames of alpha for some reason my sample names got screwed up: an X was added to the front and the "-" replaced with a ". ". I've corrected this manually now but still cannot work out which line in the code is causing this.

Comment: Your sample IDs contain dashes and start with integers, which in turn are column and row names in your phyloseq object. When you create a data.frame from e.g. a matrix R, it will replace dashes with dots (`.`) and will prepend an X to any variable starting with an integer. Here, this conversion happened in the `phyloseq::estimate_richness` function, so it's unavoidable. The easiest solution is to change the sample names before doing the richness calculation: `sample_names(ps) <- paste("sample", gsub("-", "_", sample_names(ps)), sep = "_")`.

Comment: In the future, you can avoid such bugs by providing a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as per the guidelines.